Magento 1 How to divide Products in Orders based on a Product Attribute
I have a custom Attribute in my Products. Attribute Name is warehouse_location. I have 2 warehouses in Location A and Location B.
I want to create separate orders for Items located at Location A and B.
So when my customers ordered 2 items from 2 locations in a single cart, I wanna create 2 orders for this. I am using Multishipping Checkout.
Please guide me in details how to achieve it.
Thanks in advance.
